# Create a standard page and table in drupal module with PHP

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views, drupal-modules

I made a module with a simple menu structure. I am able to programmatically retrieve a view of all my students in PHP. Now, I want to return all the students on a page in a simple table.

- How can I make a standard page?
- How can a return the values in a simple table?

The structure of the table is

UGhentID Name student First name student Location student

12874749 Smith        Nick               New York
.
.
.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to create a new page, you need to use [hook_menu](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_menu/6) in a module.

For exemple :

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_menu.
 */
function mymodule_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['myPage'] = array(
    'title' => 'Finances',
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_page',
    'access callback' => 'user_access',
    'access argument' => array('access nodes'),
  );
  return $items
}

/**
 * Page callback
 */
function mymodule_page() {
  $output = mymodule_table();
  return $output;
}
```

You can see here that I call "mymodule_table()" in the page callback, this is where you build your table.

```
function mymodule_table() {
    $rows = array();
    // build the table header
    $header = array();
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
      $header[] = array('data' =>  $i, 'class' => 'header-class');
    }
    $row = array();
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
      $row[] = array('data' =>  $i, 'class' => 'row-class');
    }
    $rows[] = array('data' => $row);
    $output .= theme('table', $header, $rows, $attributes = array('class' => 'my-table-class'));
    return $output;
}
```

This should output a table, with a header a a line a rows, with 5 columns.

Comment: This is outdated (probably for Drupal 6). For drupal 7 you need to use an updated version, where the parameters being passed to the function other than the first are an associative array. See my answer added below, I didn't have enough room in the comments.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what you mean by a 'standard page' but I think you probably want to take a look at the examples project (http://drupal.org/project/examples), in particular that page_example module.

For your table, Drupal provides a theme_table function which is pretty useful. In it's simplest form you pass an array of headers and rows and it returns the html for a table.

Comment: Yeah I liked your comment ... when give the source, not only certain answer, it will be helpful for the other

Comment: There is also an example with Edit and Delete options per row as explained [*here*](http://stackoverflow.hex1.ru/a/14682482)

Answer (score 2):

Based on @Haza's answer, here's an updated table creation function that works for Drupal 7:

```
function mymodule_table() {
    $rows = array();
    // build the table header
    $header = array();
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
      $header[] = array('data' =>  $i, 'class' => 'header-class');
    }
    $row = array();
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
      $row[] = array('data' =>  $i, 'class' => 'row-class');
    }
    $rows[] = array('data' => $row);
    $data = array(
        'header' => $header,
        'rows' => $rows,
        'attributes' => $attributes
    );
    $output = theme('table', $data);
    return $output;
}
```